# SSIS Script task (VB) to request and get Data via a SPARQL web service

Tags: vb.net, ssis, sparql, httpwebrequest

I'm after a step by step guide of creating a Script task in SSIS to query a SPARQL source and return data to a Table.
SPARQL public source available at http://statistics.data.gov.uk/data/postcodes

I cannot seem to find an example script demonstrating how a SPARQL statement can be sent and data returned.

I was thinking I could script a VB httpwebrequest script task could be used but have had no luck.